# how to get specific data from the jobs payload in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to unserialize the payload data of failed jobs how I can able to get specific data from that failed Jobs I tried most of the things like

```
   $j = App\Models\FailedJobs::select('payload')->get();
   $raw = json_decode($j[0]->payload)->data->command;
   $cm = unserialize($raw);
```

result of this example

```
App\Jobs\FailedJobs^ {#1021
+timeout: 7200
+tries: 1
#msg: array:3 [
"user_email" => Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#1019
  #items: array:8 [
    0 => " test@test.com"
  ]
 }
]
#job: null
+connection: null
+queue: null
+chainConnection: null
+chainQueue: null
+delay: null
+chained: []
}
```

How I can able access user_email from this payload object also tried with foreach but no luck

```
  public function getFailedJob()
{
    #Fetch all the failed jobs
   
    $data = [];
    
      $j = App\Models\FailedJobs::select('payload')->get();
      $raw = json_decode($j[0]->payload)->data->command;
      $cm = unserialize($raw);
    foreach ($cm as $job) {
      dd($job)
    }
```

output of this

```
7200
1
null
null
null
null
null
[]
```

the msg object is not accessible ..

Comment: Can you post some more code? Maybe the loop or other surrounding code?

Comment: @Dula yes updated the question check now

Comment: What does ``$j`` contain? An array of ``FailedJobs`` objects?

Comment: yes it contains failed jobs  object

Comment: Do you have setup getters and setters for the ``FailedJobs`` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property starts with `#` is property, you can access it by `ReflectionProperty` :

```
$property = new ReflectionProperty($cm, 'msg');
$property->setAccessible(true);
dump($property->getValue($cm));
```

Comment: ReflectionProperty' not found

Comment: add `use ReflectionProperty` to header of file or replace it with `\ReflectionProperty`

Comment: thanks it resolved the problem

Comment: can you give some explanation its just like string matching or something else  in the reflectionProperty @rubys

Comment: We can use reflection to understand the internal properties, methods, etc. of an object, or to access some non-public elements. For more information, please check the php documentation on [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)