# Trying to access key within Queue::after job payload Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pull out my `threadID` key's value from my job's payload data from within my `AppServiceProvider`'s `Queue::after` section. This is what the `payload()` contents looks like:

```json
{
   "uuid":"523d282b-3476-453f-a930-eec7ff1dbcdb",
   "displayName":"App\\Jobs\\ProcessApplication",
   "job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
   "maxTries":1,
   "maxExceptions":null,
   "failOnTimeout":true,
   "backoff":null,
   "timeout":null,
   "retryUntil":null,
   "data":{
      "commandName":"App\\Jobs\\ProcessApplication",
      "command":"O:27:\"App\\Jobs\\ProcessApplication\":3:{s:11:\"\u0000*\u0000threadID\";s:36:\"c6ac0da1-67ca-4908-8199-b474e9bd2163\";s:10:\"connection\";s:5:\"redis\";s:5:\"queue\";s:23:\"microservice--processor\";}"
   },
   "telescope_uuid":"98a38dcf-955a-4f0a-9c66-a6770149e0ac",
   "id":"523d282b-3476-453f-a930-eec7ff1dbcdb",
   "attempts":0,
   "type":"job",
   "tags":[
      
   ],
   "silenced":false,
   "pushedAt":"1678282262.8378"
}
```

I tried this:

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 */
public function boot(): void
{
    Model::shouldBeStrict(! $this->app->isProduction());

    Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
        if (str_contains(strtolower($event->job->resolveName()), 'processapplication')) {
            Log::debug('queue_after_event', [
                'job_name' => $event->job->payload()['data']['threadID']
            ]);
        }
    });
}
```

But this gives me the following error, what am I missing?

> Undefined array key "threadID" {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined array key "threadID"

Comment: Command is a serialized object, it is a string, there is no `threadId` key, just `data -> command`

Comment: `threadID` exists in `data->command`, but it's inside a serialized object, though with extra characters...

Comment: "what am I missing?"

Comment: Looks like you'll have to do some coding to get it out. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70269988/how-to-get-specific-data-from-the-jobs-payload-in-laravel and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75657741/how-to-get-the-specific-data-from-jobs-payload-command-in-laravel

Comment: If that property is on your job wouldnt $event->job->threadId suffice?